# Making variables public in MVC pattern

Tags: patterns-and-practices

In the MVC pattern, is it good programming practice to make all instance variables in the view(GUI) public so that the controller has easier access?

I started to make setters and getters for everything but then gave up because it was way too many. Why does everything have to always be private anyway?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  C# makes this trivial by providing auto-implemented getters and setters.

Comment: In Java. And it isn't just making setters and getters thats a pain, but having to use them makes code cumbersome in the controller, especially if you have a more complex GUI interface with a lot of components.

Comment: There are costs to avoiding getters and setters.  Javabeans requires them, so public members won't work.  If you ever have to convert a public member to a gettter/setter, it's a breaking change.  Make yourself some tools like an editor macro or somesuch, so that you can reduce the typing involved.

Comment: This is a reasonable question, pointing out that MVC goes against some tenets of OOP.  No great answer, but try to avoid public setters as much as possible.